# Email validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, email-validation

I am using

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/`

to validate my email IDs , but it has some issues like it is allowing below type mail ID which are invalid.

EX:

```
1.  1234@1234.com
2.  12deepak@abc.com
3.  _deepak@abc.com
```

I have tried a lot by modifying the regular expression but not succeeded.
Any one please suggest me a correct regular expression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i
```

Source: [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: It is still allowing 123@123.com type of mail IDs.

Comment: try with this: ^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$

Comment: @shemy: this is the one working fine for me thanks. up voted.